# QT 5.1.1 QML FileDialog - Unkown component (M300)

Tags: qt, qml, filedialog, qtquick2

I'm using QtQuick2 of QT 5.1.1

When I try to include and use the QML Elem `FileDialog` like described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickdialogs/qml-qtquick-dialogs1-filedialog.html#details) I just get `Unkown component (M300)`

If I hover over `import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0` it says "library at: OS-PATH/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs" but in this folder is only a DefaultFileDialog.qml some other stuff but no FileDialog.qml.

So is there any reason why my QT installation doesn't provide this QML type? How can I import it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look here, just ignore the error message. it works for me!
https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickdialogs/systemdialogs-filedialogs-qml.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no "FileDialog.qml" at all in QtQuick since the FileDialog is [implemented in C++ and exported to QML](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/f474eede801ed7bec712069e95bbe2f4ab5558ae%3asrc/imports/dialogs/plugin.cpp#L146).

Make sure to

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
```

Last but not least, ignore the warning given by QT Creator. In my case, FileDialog works perfctly but QTCreator does not know about it.